How to use @Extension Annotation with a @Path
Im trying to generate open-api specs from code, we are using jakarta and swagger oas annotations.
@Tag(name = "My beautiful API")
@Path("/api")
public class MyPathClass extends MyBaseClass {}  

Im trying to add a custom extension that would be reflected only at a path level. So something like -
    @Tag(name = "My beautiful API")
    @Path("/api")
    @Extension(name = "x-custom-options",
              properties = {
                  @ExtensionProperty(name = "key", value = "value")
              })
    public class MyPathClass extends MyBaseClass {}  

While I can add a custom annotation to a specific HTTP operation -
    @Tag(name = "My beautiful API")
    @Path("/api")
    public class MyPathClass extends MyBaseClass {
    // operation annotation     
    @Operation {
     operationID = "GET"
     @Extension(name = "x-custom-options",
              properties = {
                  @ExtensionProperty(name = "key", value = "value")
              })
       }
   }  

Im not sure if and/or how I can add it at a path level.
